# Keeping track of data with Firebase and Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on graphic chart that keeps track of integer values on a duration of 12 months, in other words, in the application it self the user selects a year and based on that year a bar chart shows the correspondent values (see the attached images below)

This is the History subcollection and the fields it has:
[image]

And this is the supposed expected result:
[image]

Problem:

The problem is I can't figure out how to update the data in the History sub-collection (currently I can retrieve it) and avoiding creating new documents, the logic behind all of this is when updating old values that hold same year and same month gets erased and replaced with the new ones.

So far this is what I have in my code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int yyyy = Calendar.YEAR;
int mm = Calendar.MONTH;

valuesList.set(mm, value);

History history = new History(yyyy, valuestListChart);
myRef.update(history);

/*This is another method I am trying so it doesn't create another document instead 
of overriding the existing one but I don't know how to go from there*/
myRef.whereEqualTo("year", 2019).get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //update logic goes here...maybe?!
            }
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

I want to update the `ArrayList<month, value>` in a way it replaces the previous value with the new one

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact data you want to update.

Comment: @AlexMamo please consider checking the update I made, the structure is above in the first attached picture

Comment: First off all, `ArrayList<month, value>` does **not** exist in Java. Second, please add a screenshot of your database and indicate on that, what is the exact data that you want to update.